# facebook graph api in ios error- Unknown path components

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook graph api in ios to share a news feed from iphone. But i get the following error:

```
 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2500;
        message = "Unknown path components: /http://newswatch.nationalgeographic.com/2013/01/20/top-25-wild-bird-photographs-of-the-week-34;
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;

}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

following is part of my code to share a newsfeed on btnClick:

```
if ([strType isEqualToString:@"link"]) {


        text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"caption"];
        if (text == nil) {
            text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"name"];
        }
        if (text == nil) {
            text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"story"];
        }
        NSDictionary *dict = [resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];



        dic=[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text,@"message",nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", dict);
       // NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];
        NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];
        request=[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"me/feed/"];
        [request appendString:str];
         NSLog(@"appended : %@", request);
    }
```

same code works if i try to share a photo type of newsfeed. where am i getting wrong? how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Could you share the code where you're making the API call? One quick thing is you may want to think of passing your parameters, ex: link, separately instead of appending it to the me/feed endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the error: correct code:

if ([strType isEqualToString:@"link"] || [strType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {

```
        text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"caption"];
        if (text == nil) {
            text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"name"];
        }
        if (text == nil) {
            text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"story"];
        }
        NSDictionary *dict = [resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

        NSLog(@"%@", dict);

        NSString *str = [dict valueForKey:@"link"];
        dic=[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:str,@"link",nil];
        request=[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"me/feed/"];

         NSLog(@" %@", dic);
    }
```

in request we only need to pass me/feed and in params of FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:request parameters:dic HTTPMethod:@"POST"]; we need to pass link=http://...